# Is there a way to exit a Greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I know that you can use `return;` to return from a Greasemonkey script, but only if you aren't in another function. For example, this won't work:

```
// Begin greasemonkey script
function a(){
    return; // Only returns from the function, not the script
}
// End greasemonkey script
```

Is there a built in Greasemonkey function that would allow me to halt execution of the script, from anywhere in the script?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, you can probably do something like:

```
(function loop(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(parameter === "abort") {
            throw new Error("Stopped JavaScript.");
        }
        loop();
  }, 1000);
})(parameter);
```

You can simply abort your script by setting the value of variable parameter to abort, this can either be a regular variable or a Greasemonkey variable. If it's a Greasemonkey variable, then you can modify it directly through the browser using about:config in Firefox.

Comment: I was thinking of throwing an error. But, will this interfere with other scripts on the page?

Comment: @SimpleCoder, No. My other Greasemonkey scripts, for the same page, and the native scripts works fine.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a built in Greasemonkey function that would allow me to halt execution of the script, from anywhere in the script?

No.  [These are the current Greasemonkey functions](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Greasemonkey_Manual%3aAPI).

You can throw an exception, like Anders' answer, but I prefer not to exception-out except in exceptional circumstances.

There's always the old classic, `do-while`...

```
// Begin greasemonkey script
var ItsHarikariTime = false;

do {
    function a(){
        ItsHarikariTime = true;
        return; // Only returns from the function, not the script
    }
    if (ItsHarikariTime)    break;

} while (0)
// End greasemonkey script
```

Alternatively, you could use function returns instead of the local global.

Comment: Just a little addition: The `do-while` trick works with nested loops too, if you use a label: `main: do { /*...*/ break main;} while (false);`

Comment: The problem here is that you need to move big chunks of code around and place it within the do/while, while my solution is just append to the start of the GM script.

Answer (score 2):

If you are inside a nested call of functions, **throw** seems like the only solution to quit the script all together. However, if you want to quit the script somewhere within the script (not inside a function call), I suggest wrapping all the script into an anonymous function.

```
// begin greasemonkey script

(function(){


// all contents of the script, can include function defs and calls
...
...
if <...>
    return;  // this exits the script
...
...



})(); // this calls the whole script as a single function
```