# Userscript turned Firefox-addon is not running in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm new to addon development. [Here](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/13948-nice-reddit/code) is the simple user-script that I'm trying to convert into a firefox-addon. And this is just a simple private addon I'm going to use, not for AMO or something. The reason I'm converting this to an addon in first place is that Firefox for Android doesn't support the `greasemonkey` extension yet.

So, I referred to Wladimir Palant's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667776/how-do-i-publish-a-greasemonkey-script-as-a-firefox-add-on) and went about building my addon by referring to mozilla docs. Here is my folder structure which I created my using `jpm init`:

```
--data>
    - redditplus.js //my userscript file. 
--index.js //main entry point
--package.json
--README.md
```

Here are the contents of `index.js`, the main entry point:

```
var data = require("self").data;
var pageMod = require("page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.reddit.com/*",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("redditplus.js"),
  contentScriptWhen: 'start'
});
```

I then go about building my addon like this:

```
jpm xpi
```

But when I install the compiled `@redditplus-0.0.1.xpi` addon in firefox, it doesn't work! The userscript is supposed to highlight any unread reddit comments or at least write some logs to console, but it is doing nothing. What am I missing here?

Comment: I didn't think you could install unsigned addons any more. Which version of firefox? did you try the browser console (`ctrl`+`shift`+`j`) sometimes errors appear there that don't appear on the developer tools console

Comment: I'm using Firefox 41.0.2 on Ubuntu Linux, and it didn't complain when I installed the addon (though it asked for confirmation). And yes, I'm scanning the console for logs and the addon isn't writing a thing there.

Comment: if you go to about:addons then in `extensions` - is your extension enabled. I don't know what you mean by `scanning the console` ... just to be clear, I'm talking about the broswer console that opens when you type ctrl+shift+j

Comment: FYI - a shortcut for `data.url("redditplus.js")` is just `"./redditplus.js"` - not part of your issue, but it also saves having to require ("self").data

Comment: It is very much enabled, it just shows a warning that **Reddit Plus could not be verified for use in Firefox**. And yes, I know the shortcut, but I copied the code from Wladimir's answer verbatim to make it sure it runs good the first time.

Comment: All good, just making sure

Comment: that answer you linked to suggests `*.reddit.com` would include `reddit.com` - I don't see anywhere in MDN docs that suggests this is true ... ahh, but reddit.com redirects to www.reddit.com anyway, so that's not the problem :p

Comment: all I can suggest is trying `include: "https://www.reddit.com/*"`

Comment: Regarding `scanning the console`, I was referring to the same thing. I did `Ctrl+shift+K` that opened the firefox console window at bottom where all logs are visible. `Ctrl+shift+J` opens a separate window, but it shows the same thing.

Comment: `ctrl+shift+k` shows console for current tab ... `ctrl+shift+j` shows all console logs and then some

Comment: Tried including `https://www.reddit.com/*`, but it didn't work. The new include definition is this: `include: ["*.reddit.com/*", "https://www.reddit.com/*"],`. Btw, `jpm xpi` doesn't validate my code before compilation. Is there a utility that I can use to check before compilation ?

Comment: I use `jshint` ...i install using `npm install -g jshint` then you should be able to just run `jshint index.js` etc ..  though, there may be better tools for checking js code out there, I just stick with what I know :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The userscript has the following clause:

```
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
```

Which means it needs jquery to work.

You need to include the appropriate jquery file in your addon and pass it like this:

```
contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery.js"), data.url("redditplus.js")]
```

> The userscript is supposed to highlight any unread reddit comments or at least write some logs to console

To get log messages from SDK addons you need to set the following in *about:config*

```
extensions.sdk.console.logLevel = info
```

And open the browser console (ctrl+shift+j) instead of the tab's devtools console.

Another thing: Since the default for userscripts is `@run-at document-end` using `contentScriptWhen: 'start'` will probably break the script.

Comment: Thanks! I've added the jQuery dependency and enabled `logLevel`. Now I'm getting this error in console when the addon is run: `Object { _errorType: "SyntaxError", message: "return not in function", fileName: "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/too…", lineNumber: 18, stack: "", name: "SyntaxError" }`

Comment: sounds like a regular javascript error to me, nothing firefox specific. surely you don't expect me to do all the work for you?

Comment: Yup. Turns out that I can't put a regular `return false;` in an addon main script. Instead, I had to do `throw new Error()` as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651452/is-there-a-way-to-exit-a-greasemonkey-script). Thanks!